# Django: how to change input and label render in as_ul, as_p and as_table methods

Tags: django

by default, Django forms render inputs wrapping them in label:

```
<label for="id_field_35_2">
<input id="id_field_35_2" type="radio" value="val" name="field_35">input text
</label>
```

With our new CSS styles we need to write them separately -

```
<input id="id_field_35_2" type="radio" value="val" name="field_35">
<label for="id_field_35_2">input text</label>
```

Is there any way to change Django rendering to this way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Render them manually, as shown in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)

Comment: I would, but between field.html_name, field.label_tag etc I can't find the attribute who would let me to understand the type of the field (radio, checkbox etc).

Comment: Also, while everybody says opposite, {{ form.as_p }} is not the same as {% for field in form %} {{ field }} {% endfor %}.
Our form contains some labels alone (don't ask me why...). They're rendered with *.as_p OK, but for ... field... endfor doesn't include them to the rendering.

Comment: `{{ field }}` should correctly render input control entirely, with type attribute set.
As for labels - how do you add them on the form (I mean, show some code)?

Answer (score 0):

You could add css classes to the fields rendered by django using [`widget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) attribute of `Form` class.